# Move rect in NSView

Tags: objective-c, nsview, cgrect

I've got a NSView subclass "graphics" where some rects are drawn.

Now I want a public method to move/resize the rects. I tried to set a new origins, but that doesn't work for me.

```
rect.origin.x = anything;
```

Now how can I move the rects?

regards

Comment: That code isn't changing anything on the NSView side, you're just altering the rect and hoping the view will notice.  It doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the rectangles in a method called "drawRect", which is run every time the NSView thinks it should need to redisplay itself.

Your problem is that you are setting the initial location of the rectangles in this method, so every changed you make in other method wouldn't matter and would be reset every time. You should instead set the rectangles initial location in methods like init or awakeFromNib that only happen once.

After your button changed the values of the origin of the rectangle, you can tell the view to redraw itself, using :

```
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

So add this after the code that changes the rect origin and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi first thanks for your answer.
I tried that already to do this in the same NSView Class but then it tells me: " No known class method for selector 'setNeedsDisplay'

Comment: Wait now it's an instance method, but doesn't work either.
Code: `- (void)move:(int)d{
       if (d==1) {
        stab1.origin.x = 5;
           [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        NSLog(@"test");
    }
}`
The method is called and in the log appears "test" but "stab1" doesn't realign ?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the code of your class? How is the Move method being called?

Comment: Yes sorry, here is the link I made a screenshot:[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uiad2ccurtlpuga/Bildschirmfoto%202014-10-17%20um%2019.59.30.png?dl=0)

Comment: Yes, here it is :) [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4ifdzgh36z0op5/Bildschirmfoto%202014-10-18%20um%2012.02.22.png?dl=0)

Comment: I can see your problem now, Edited with the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I think I don't do it right. 
I made a new screenshot:[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4b342wj6vc6r4j/Bildschirmfoto%202014-10-18%20um%2013.27.09.png?dl=0)
The rectangles are initialized right and the origin changes I can see it in the console but it doesn't redraw right?